# Using arithmetic operators in turtle.setpos()

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I am trying to get variable c to be divided by 2 in a setpos()

```
import turtle
jeff = turtle.Turtle()
jeff.penup()
jeff.shape("square")
jeff.shapesize(.5,.5,.5)
def ask():
    a = raw_input("pick one of the following colors: (red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, black)")
    b = raw_input("pick another one of the following colors: (red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, black)")
    c = raw_input("how many squares long do you want the patern to be: ")
    jeff.setpos(-(c/2*2+11), c/2*11)
    for lap in range(0, c/2):
        for lap in range(0, c/2):
            jeff.forward(11)
            jeff.color(a)
            jeff.stamp()
            jeff.forward(11)
            jeff.color(b)
            jeff.stamp()
        jeff.right(90)
        jeff.forward(11)
        jeff.right(90)
        for lap in range(0, c/2):
            jeff.color(a)
            jeff.stamp()
            jeff.forward(11)
            jeff.color(b)
            jeff.stamp()
            jeff.forward(11)
        jeff.left(90)
        jeff.forward(11)
        jeff.left(90)

ask()
```

when i enter the data it says

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = raw_input("how many squares long do you want the patern to be: ")
```

will return the user input as a string. Dividing a String by an int (in the next line) does not make any sense and results in the error you are seeing.

What you want is:

```
c = int(raw_input("how many squares long do you want the patern to be: "))
```

This will get the input number as a string from `raw_input()` and then convert it to an integer.